# Calculate the statistical mean of different files and save it into a CSV file

Tags: python, performance, pandas, statistics

In this code I calculate the statistical functions of values from different files and save them into CSV files (one filer for each statistical function).

```py
def mean(data):
    pass

def standard_deviation(data):
    pass

def afd(data):
    pass

def norma_afd(data):
    pass

def asd(data):
    pass

def norma_asd(data):
    pass

def calculation(file):
    """
    Get the DataFrame and calculate for ever column the different statistical mean
    :param file: DataFrame 56x7681
    :return: 6 different 56x1 lists for (mean, std, afd, norm_afd, asd, norm_asd)
    """
    m, sd, afd_l, nafd, asd_l, nasd = ([] for _ in range(6))
    for column in file:
        data = file[column].to_numpy()
        m.append(mean(data))
        sd.append(standard_deviation(data))
        afd_l.append(afd(data))
        nafd.append(norma_afd(data))
        asd_l.append(asd(data))
        nasd.append(norma_asd(data))
    return m, sd, afd_l, nafd, asd_l, nasd

def run(load_path, save_path):
    """
    Get (yield) all the different DataFrame from a folder
    and calculate for each file the statistical mean and save it in a csv file

    :param load_path: the folder path to load all the different files
    :param save_path: the folder save path
    :return: none
    """
    m, sd, afd_l, nafd, asd_l, nasd = ([] for _ in range(6))
    for current_path, file in yield_data(load_path, data_type="data"):
        a, b, c, d, e, f = calculation(file)
        m.append(a)
        sd.append(b)
        afd_l.append(c)
        nafd.append(d)
        asd_l.append(e)
        nasd.append(f)

    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.makedirs(save_path)

    pd.DataFrame(m).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "mean.csv", index=False, header=False)
    pd.DataFrame(sd).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "std.csv", index=False, header=False)
    pd.DataFrame(afd_l).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "afd.csv", index=False, header=False)
    pd.DataFrame(nafd).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "norm_afd.csv", index=False, header=False)
    pd.DataFrame(asd_l).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "asd.csv", index=False, header=False)
    pd.DataFrame(nasd).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + "norm_asd.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to write this code? This may be a stupid question, but I would be really interested to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you missing some `import` statements?  Please [edit] to complete the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code cannot be run, here is a wild guess on a way to restructure it:

```py
def mean(fileResults, data):
    result = 0
    # do computation
    fileResults["mean"].append(result)

def standard_deviation(fileResults, data):
    pass

def afd(fileResults, data):
    pass

def norma_afd(fileResults, data):
    pass

def asd(fileResults, data):
    pass

def norma_asd(fileResults, data):
    pass

def calculation(file):
    """
    Get the DataFrame and calculate for ever column the different statistical mean
    :param file: DataFrame 56x7681
    :return: 6 different 56x1 lists for (mean, std, afd, norm_afd, asd, norm_asd)
    """
    fileResults = {
        "mean": [],
        "std": [],
        "afd": [],
        "norm_afd": [],
        "asd": [],
        "norm_asd": [],
        }

    functionCallList = [
        mean,
        standard_deviation,
        afd,
        norma_afd,
        asd,
        norma_asd,
        ]

    for column in file:
        data = file[column].to_numpy()

        for functionCall in functionCallList:
            functionCall(fileResults, data)

    return fileResults

def run(load_path, save_path):
    """
    Get (yield) all the different DataFrame from a folder
    and calculate for each file the statistical mean and save it in a csv file

    :param load_path: the folder path to load all the different files
    :param save_path: the folder save path
    :return: none
    """
    results = {}

    for current_path, file in yield_data(load_path, data_type="data"):
        fileResults = calculation(file)

        for key, value in fileResults.items():
            if key not in results:
                results[key] = []

            results[key].append(value)

    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.makedirs(save_path)

    for key, value in results.items():
        pd.DataFrame(value).to_csv(save_path + os.path.sep + key + ".csv", index=False, header=False)
```

So, instead of repeating function call, mostly when function prototypes are the same, you can use a list of function callbacks. Then just iterate it.

You can also use a dictionnary to store your data, instead of n lists. It's a little bit more scalable, and clearer than returning a 6-tuple. It also avoids a lot of copy-paste when you save csv files.

Comment: Agree, list of function is way to go.

Comment: @VincentRG To work correct for my purpose I initial the dictionary `fileResults` in `calculation` with `{"mean": [], "std": [], "afd": [], "norm_afd": [], "asd": [], "norm_asd": []}`  and the calculation methods append to the lists. But many thanks for your solution.

Comment: Yes you're right, several columns per file are parsed, and for each column you do all computations. Hence the need for appending to each list for each column. I haven't seen that.